# cppcheck can't detect leaks when heap pointers are passed to functions?

Tags: c, cppcheck

Why does `cppcheck` fail to detect a memory leak in a program like this example, where ownership of a heap pointer is passed to a function that fails to free it?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(char *xx)
{
    // do nothing
}

int main(void)
{
    char *p = malloc(1000);
    func(p);
    return 0;
}
```

If I remove the call to `func(p)` then cppcheck does detect the leak.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: I have reworded this question to clarify what I think you are asking.  I also corrected some minor errors in your code, which may have distracted people from the point of the question.  If I have misunderstood please let me know.

Comment: Ownership isn't necessarily passed to func, func can just access the memory. The intent was that main() would free the pointer. cppcheck seems to assume that the ownership has been passed yet it does not validate that the memory was actually freed.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Cppcheck 1.69](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net) and this correctly informed me there was a memory leak. I have the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(char *xx)
{
    // do nothing
}

int main(void)
{
    char *p = (char*)malloc(1000);
    func(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I have converted `malloc` to a `char*` to compile, but I tried Cppcheck with the **exact same code** you posted and it still correctly told me there was a memory leak.

When I run:

```
cppcheck main.cpp
```

I'm presented the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Cppcheck>cppcheck main.cpp
Checking main.cpp...
[main.cpp:12]: (error) Memory leak: p
```

I checked the [change log for 1.69](http://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/news/2015/05/cppcheck-169/) and interestingly it says:

> Improvements:
>   - Improved buffer overrun and memory leak checking

Cppcheck also correctly informs me of a memory leak if I use `new`:

```
char* p = new char;
func(p);
```

And if I deallocate the memory in `func` there is no error:

```
void func(char *xx)
{
    delete p;
}

int main(void)
{
    char* p = new char;
    func(p);
    return 0;
}
```

If I allocate with `malloc` and try to deallocate with `delete` in `func`, Cppcheck also informs me of a `mismatchAllocDealloc` error.